# Is Chuck the Evil Sandwich Making Guy's head actually a sandwich?

Tags: wordgirl

Well here's a weird one for ya.

On the kids' show *WordGirl* there was a villain named 'Chuck The Evil Sandwich Making Guy' whose head appeared to be a sandwich with a pair of goggles around his eyes, I never really could tell if his head was a sandwich or if it was just a helmet. Does anyone know? Here's what he looked like.

[image]

Comment: Well he’s wearing goggles with no straps, so either those are fused to his head or he’s wearing a mask.

Comment: @TannerBurkhead I've moved your answer to be a comment. Feel free to answer again but provide more evidence to back up what you're saying and any that makes an answer

Answer (score 17, accepted):

According to Liz Breen, the show's associate producer, he has an *actual* sandwich for a head. The *why* remains elusive.

> **Q:** *I've been meaning to ask, why is Chuck part-sandwich? Every time he
> eats a sandwich, or when he ate that one shaped like Wordgirl, isn't
> he being cannibalistic?? >XD*
>
> **Liz Breen:** *Oh my God, Karen. You can’t just ASK people why they’re part sandwich.*
>
> <sub><sup>[LizBreenWrites](https://lizbreenwrites.tumblr.com/search/sandwich)</sup></sub>

Answer (score 9):

According to villains.fandom.com, yes, his head is a sandwich.

> Chuck's most distinguished feature compared to the other antagonists **is that he has a sandwich for a head**, and it appears to be an inherited trait since his brother Brent also has this feature. However, it has not been shown if his mother also shares this trait, since she is never seen.
>   <sub>source [villains.fandom.com](https://villains.fandom.com/wiki/Chuck_the_Evil_Sandwich_Making_Guy)</sub>

This is backed up by some [other internet sources](https://www.pinterest.ca/pin/383861568230775506/) but they could all be quoting from the same anonymous source.

The closest thing I could find to a canon source comes from nhpbs.org.

> In this clip, WordGirl and Huggy are held captive by the Evil Sandwich Making Guy. **He has a sandwich for a head** and mustard and catsup on his utility belt. He uses hot dogs to tie up WordGirl and Huggy.
>   <sub>source [New Hampshire Public Television](http://writenator.nhptv.org/main_challenge.asp?aid=4)</sub>

[Word Girl](https://pbskids.org/wordgirl/) is a PBS Kids show and NHPBS is a PBS affiliate.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the two answers, a couple of other pieces of evidence point to it being his head.

[image]

His brother, Brent, pretty unambiguously has a sandwich for a head.

[image]

Additionally, in the episode "Lunch Lady Chuck," he loses his job as a lunch fellow because he won't wear a hairnet that pinches him. This indicates that the lettuce is actually his hair. Otherwise, he wouldn't have to wear a hairnet over it or he could take it off to avoid discomfort.